# Joomla user can visit a site only one time

Tags: joomla, time

I want that my registered users can visit a specific site only one time. Is there any way to get this working?

Big big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

if user login success get last vist date

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo '<p>Register date: ' . $user->registerDate . '</p>';
echo '<p>Last visited: ' . $user->lastvisitDate . '</p>';
```

and check if lastvisitDate exist redirect to ANOTHER_PAGE and logout the current user

LOGOUT:

```
$app->logout( $user_id );
```